# Is there a way to improve copy of folder structure to a network location

Tags: c#, windows

If you are copying many folders with files inside it can be usually better to just create a ZIP/RAR with the folder and files, copy it to network path and unzip it. This usually works much faster than copy paste

Is there a way to do this programatically and embed it into windows so that It can try to detect which way is faster and use that one (normal way or "compress on the fly") to improve speed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"compression on the fly" is a waste unless there is something on the other end that can perform the decompress OR if the compressed state is acceptable.  That said:

Yes, you can write an app that zips/rars files.

Yes, you can have that app copy the zip/rar to a network directory.

Yes, you can have an app on the other end wait for the file and unzip it locally...

Can you have it detect "which way is faster"??  Although possible it is unlikely to be of benefit for anything other than large files... at which point you should always zip/rar and transfer...which would make the entire exercise rather pointless.  Of course, you should probably evaluate the data that is likely to be transferred using your app to see if it is even a candidate for compression.  Video, for example, might not be...

More to the point here, each end would have to have an application that is aware of each other (or at least the protocols involved).  One app (we'll call it the *client*) would zip and post the file to another app (we'll call that one the *server*).  When the *server* receives the file it would unzip it and store it on the file system.

**update**
I thought of another situation for zipping: transferring LOTs of little files at one time.  Normal network file copy routines go much faster for a single large file vs lots of little files.  So, if they are selecting a few hundred files to go at once you might be better off always zipping.  Which, incidentally, doesn't change the requirement of having something on the other side able to decompress it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `robocopy` ? It's built-in on Windows, robust, multi-threaded and features a lot of options, including mirroring and retries in case of failure. I use it with all copy to network locations. Give it a try.

Comment: does robocopy support "compression on the fly" to reduce transfer times ?

Comment: No `robocopy` doesn't support "compression on the fly". Back on your initial question: to figure which way is faster, you have to take account of the time of compression (more or less depending on the CPU) and the bandwidth of your network. I usually transfer very "heavy" directories across network locations and compression never been worth it for me. Again it depends on how effective your compression is which depends on the type of data you're working with. I don't think there would be a trivial way to solve your problem.